# Как на слайд добавить URL источник?

Tags: android, android-studio

Помогите пожалуйста, как добавить url источник видео(код) Android Studio?

---

MainActivity.java

```html
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sliderpager = findViewById(R.id.slider_pager);
        indicator = findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        MoviesRV = findViewById(R.id.rv_cast);

        // Список слайдов
        IstSlides = new ArrayList<>() ;
        IstSlides.add(new Slide(R.drawable.slide1,  "[FLS] Only The Strong Survive ANNIVERSARY MEP"));
        
        IstSlides.add(new Slide(R.drawable.slide2,  "Love the way you lie MEP"));
        IstSlides.add(new Slide(R.drawable.slide3,  "[ 家族 ] Faithful MEP"));
        IstSlides.add(new Slide(R.drawable.slide4,  "NARUTO AMV - Hurts Our Friendship"));
        IstSlides.add(new Slide(R.drawable.slide5,  "[DorkS] Little Wonders ᴹᴱᴾ"));
        IstSlides.add(new Slide(R.drawable.slide6,  "❝ find your way.❞ ♫ shigatsu wa kimi no uso ─ collab w_⁄ my soulmate ♥"));
        IstSlides.add(new Slide(R.drawable.slide7,  "[凪のあすから] Meps ♥ ll ❝ Walk on the water ❞ ᴹᴱᴾ"));
        IstSlides.add(new Slide(R.drawable.slide8,  "[Pokemon AMV] - Memories -"));
        IstSlides.add(new Slide(R.drawable.slide9,  "MEP ¦¦ Shouldnt Be A Good in Goodbye"));
        IstSlides.add(new Slide(R.drawable.slide10,  "World Trigger | Monster AMV"));
        IstSlides.add(new Slide(R.drawable.slide11,  "「ⓀⒾⓃ」《Full AMV》"));
        SliderPagerAdapter adapter = new SliderPagerAdapter( this,IstSlides);
        sliderpager.setAdapter(adapter);
        //время установки
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MainActivity.SliderTimer(), 4000, 6000);
        indicator.setupWithViewPager(sliderpager, true);
```

Comment: Вам надо тогда переделать адаптер для списках и добавить туда еще один параметр.